# How to insert data in multiple tables if tables have relationship OneToMany, and @Column(unique = true)

Tags: sql, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have two tables `MAKES` and `MODELS`. Between them relationship `@ManyToOne`.

Table `MAKES`:

```
@Column(unique = true)
private String make;
```

Table `MODELS`:

```
@Column(unique = true)
private String model;
```

When I insert schema `car`:

```
makes.setMake("Porsche");
models.setModel("911");

em.persist(makes);
em.persist(models);
```

Data is added, but if `Porsche` exist in `MAKES` table an exception is returned: `... Duplicate entry 'Porsche' for key ...`.

Comment: Is this really related to the <sql> _language_? (I see no SQL above. Do you expect a SQL answer?)

Comment: @jarlh  I had hoped, that in database have native method insert "Porsche 911", as insert only "911" and relationship with "Porsche", if "Porsche" exist. Can I tune in MySQL another reaction on "Duplicate entry" event?

Comment: You have a uniqueness constraint on a random field/column in what you've shown us, and are calling 'persist' aka insert for something that is a duplicate - this constraint violation error is supposed to happen. You should show your classes and the relationship, but this is a standard situation that is covered under many JPA tutorials, where one set of data exists and needs to be referenced from a new set of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This constraint violation error is supposed to happen to prevent you from accidentally doing what you are doing here - inserting two separate Make instances that both have the Make column value of "Porsche". If you need to have multiple Makes with the value "Porsche", you need to relax the constraint to allow duplicates.

What seems more likely is this is intended, and you have an existing Make that you want to associate to or under a new Model. Read in the existing make from the DB and use that managed instance within your EntityManager context instead of trying to persist a new Make instance.

Ie

```
  Query q = em.createQuery("select m from Make m where m.make = 'Porsche'");
  Make Porsche = q.getSingleResult();
  models.setModel("911");
  models.setMake(Porsche);
  em.persist(models);
```

Answer (score -1):

you must save two table in two Transaction if you want one Transaction before  sava Make table must check unique row after that save it. when in one Transaction create one exception the Transaction reverse.

Comment: Did I understand correctly? I can`t tune reaction the duplicate entry in last version MySQL and JPA. I must to create this exception myself?